# Unable to connect RDS MySQL Database through AWS Datapipeline

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-data-pipeline

I have created a AWS Datapipeline to move data from RDS MySQL Database into S3, But i an getting below error. Please help

amazonaws.datapipeline.connector.SqlInputConnector: The query string is: select * from DB.EMP
02 May 2020 12:23:52,091 [ERROR] (TaskRunnerService-resource:df-09331673GUKZ0M06WINA_@Ec2Instance_2020-05-02T12:21:43-0) df-09331673GUKZ0M06WINA amazonaws.datapipeline.database.ConnectionFactory: Unable to establish connection to jdbc:mysql://mysql-nikhil-db-intance.ckmzsndysx7u.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/null Unknown database 'null'

Note : I am able to query the database using Mysql workbench,also created 2 inbound rules under security groups as per the attached screen[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is working when i have moved my DynamoDB table region into region of my data pipeline